# xcode 9 stuck loading on main.storyboard interface builder

Tags: xcode, xcode9.2

My XCode loads indefinitely when I try to access Main.storyboard. I've tried all the solutions to the answers on here, but they're for XCode 8, not XCode 9. I have the latest version, XCode 9.2. Is there any way to solve this? Please help, thanks!

**Edit:** LaunchScreen.storyboard works, but not Main.storyboard.